# Using interfaces in C++ with STL containers

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I have two structs that had methods in common, that are defined in an Interface (I can't change these):

```
struct Interface {
   virtual int Foo() = 0;
};
struct A : Interface {
  virtual int Foo() override;
  //A specific methods etc  
};
struct B : Interface {
  virtual int Foo() override;
  //B specific methods etc
};
```

If there's a function that needs to take an Interface then it's pretty simple:
    //a member variable
    std::vector m_as;

```
int DoubleFoo( Interface& obj ) {
  return obj.Foo() * 2;
}

DoubleFoo(m_as[0]);
```

However if there's a function that needs multiple Interface then it's not so simple:

```
int SumFoo( std::vector<Interface>& objs ) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (auto&& obj : objs ) {
    sum += obj.Foo();
  }
  return sum;
}
```

because if I have an existing (eg member) variable of `std::vector<A>` I can't simply do:

```
SumFoo(m_as);
```

Instead I have to either change SumFoo to `std::vector<Interface*>` and have to create a new vector of pointers that point to the elements in the original array.

Or just cast it in the function call, which is quite ugly:

```
SumFoo((std::vector<Interface>&)m_as);
```

How is it possible to easily/nicely use interfaces in C++, when it comes to something as simple as needing a vector of them?

I understand why I can't pass a subclass to a function expecting it's base class by value because of object slicing etc. But why isn't the cast from `std::vector<Derived>*` to `std::vector<Base>*` implicit, when `Derived*` to `Base*` is?

I guess the problem would be you could add a Base() to the vector whcih would cause problems in the calling code because it thinks it's a vector of Derived, but then you could just make the argument const, and Base is abstract anyway.

Comment: `SumFoo((std::vector<Interface>&)m_as);` is also quite UB.

Comment: @LogicStuff, why?

Comment: Inheritance in c++ does not work with by-value calls. If you want to group things by base class you have to have Pointers or references.

Comment: If you cannot use a vector of pointers, the last remaining option is a template function, with code bloat being a small price to pay.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I have and it did compile: http://ideone.com/x1yaTD

Comment: @Hayt, I'm aware inheritance doesn't work with by-value calls. But this is using references to vectors (and could be with pointers)

Comment: I stand corrected. It'll compile, but will result in UB at runtime.

Comment: The elements inside of your vector are still by value. Just because you have a pointer/ref to the vector does not make the elements inside the vector a reference/pointer too.

Comment: @Hayt, Yes I know, but because the vector is a reference then the elements won't be copied and object slicing won't take place. And if I use the [] operator or `at` function to access an element, it will provide a *reference* to the element, so everything will still be valid.

Comment: You also can use templates.

Comment: @NicolBolas, that question is about passing the vector by value, not reference... I completely understand why std::vector<Derived> is not castable to std::vector<Base>, I don't understand why `const std::vector<Derived>&` is not castable to `const std::vector<Base>&`

Comment: No, everything will not "still be valid". Change fn() to use `reg.at(1)`, and watch your program crash and burn. You cannot cast a vector this way.

Comment: That is not really how that works. The size of an Derived object does not have to be the same as the base object. So when you iterate/access the elements in the memory a wrong size is assumed and the reference you get points to some undefined memory

Comment: @Jonathan.: "*that question is about passing the vector by value, not reference...*" They're both not allowed for the same reason. The same answer answers both questions.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, ok I had tried that but only tried it on the first element which worked, obviously it doesn't work on the second element onwards.

Comment: @NicolBolas, nowhere in that question/answer does it mention about references. I only understand now thanks to Sam and Hayt. So closing it was as counter productive as usual, as I could have marked their answer as accepted, but now there's just a long list of comments..

Comment: @Jonathan.: "*nowhere in that question/answer does it mention about references.*" That's because it's *irrelevant*. Whether it's values or references, it will not work. And it will not work *for the same reason*: that the two types are *unrelated*.

Comment: OP may also want to look into [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate), since they can do this: [`std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0, [](int sum, Interface& i){return sum + i.Foo();});`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95974b6a2b47a8cd)